# YAJLiOS can't parse non English letters?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, yajl

i have question about YAJLiOS parser...
I have next json data :

```
   {{
    body = "Привет";
    mid = 3;
    "read_state" = 1;
   }
   { body = "hi";
     mid = 3;
     "read_state" = 1;
    }}
```

and i'm trying to get "body" , result is : "\U0416\U0412" and "hi"

it might be problem with encoding, but i have no idea how to fix it

**Thanks for your time!**

Comment: Can you show the code from where you are doing the parsing?

Comment: sure:

 NSString *getFriendDialogs = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.vk.com/method/messages.getHistory?access_token=%@&uid=%@&chat_id=uid&count=10",currentAccessToken,UidOfSelectedFriend];
   
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:getFriendDialogs];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    
     NSData *tempContainer = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requestObj 
     returningResponse:nil
     error:nil];

     NSDictionary *dialogsDictionary = [tempContainer yajl_JSON];
     idString = [dialogsDictionary valueForKey:@"body"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to convert to a string first to deal with the UTF-8 character encoding.

```
NSData *tempContainer = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requestObj returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSString *tempString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[tempContainer bytes]];

NSDictionary *dialogsDictionary = [tempString yajl_JSON];
```

Comment: is there other character encoding that i can use?

Comment: NSData tempContainer = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requestObj returningResponse:nil error:nil]; NSString content = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:tempContainer encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; all is ok when i use this code,but need nsdictionary not nsstring